# Retain CSS Animation Color Fill

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to create a transforming logo that changes color on scroll. I have simplified my css to make it simpler to explain.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-change {
        100% {fill:blue}
}

.change{
  fill:red;
  -webkit-animation: rotate-change;
}
```

The item with the class of ".change" starts of with a fill color of red. What I wanted was the fill color to change to blue after the animation ends, as the "-webkit-keyframes" does. The only problem is that during the animation, the fill color changes from red to blue, but when the animation finishes, the fill color reverts back to red. Is there a way to permanently keep the fill color of the animation, even after it ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the fill just reverts back to the original color...

Comment: @corybantic It was supposed to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

Comment: It's supposed to work, but I'm not so sure why... I'll keep on trying to see what's wrong with my code. :)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to animate a SVG logo to rotate to form a ribbon and also to change color. The actual code is much longer (and messier) so I just wanted a simple example of how to retain the color after animation.

Comment: Ah! I was using jQuery to trigger the animations on scroll, so I have to put -animation-fill-mode: forwards in the jQuery Css code, not the normal CSS code! Thanks @Akshay!!

Comment: Yep! :D (Sorry for the late replies)